# Validate Firebase with rules when data is written by firebase-admin

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

From what I understand, the default account used with `admin.initializeApp()` has Editor privilege, which seems to disregard all validation and permission rules

Am I missing something? It seems non-sensical to have the default service account (i.e. server processes writing to Firebase) bypass rules altogether when writing to Firebase. Especially since this the documented way in the samples & in the docs, and that the rules simulator gives zero indication that these rules will **not** be enforced on certain accounts

My context is a Cloud Function that push something back to Firebase, and I want to be able to validate it with `.validate`

Comment: I just spent the last 30 minutes going through my rules and trying to figure out why they weren't validating my data until I finally hypothesized that the admin-sdk might bypass validation. This needs more attention in the docs google!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already discovered the Firebase Admin SDK runs with administrative privileges, which bypasses all security rules. From the [documentation on getting started with the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup):

> The Admin SDK lets you interact with Firebase from privileged environments to perform actions like:
>
> - Read and write Realtime Database data with full admin privileges.

The logic here is that your code that uses the Admin SDK runs in a trusted environment, where you can trust that the code is what you wrote and thus works according to your specification.

It isn't currently possible to use the Admin SDK while also enforcing security rules. I suggest you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Note that what you want **is** possible with the realtime database, as shown in [Authenticate with limited privileges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges).

For Firestore you can control some of the access within the Cloud Identity and Access Management console. See the [documentation on securing your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#secure_your_data).

Comment: Thanks for the details/links. I guess I wanted to make sure that I had understood it correctly. Will look further into limited priviledges auth

Comment: Please do, and let me know your findings. As I was going through the docs, I wasn't as certain anymore as to what is possible, hence the number of links. I'd love to hear it if it is somehow possible to limit Firestore access from the Admin SDK, as it is already possible for the Realtime Database.